# PostgreSQL: test if user exists else create new user returning his id

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.1

I am trying to create a query that satisfies the following:

Given a username and an email address,

- test if the username or the email is already taken and if not, INSERT INTO user_account (username, email_address, hash)
- return (as an integer) `user_id` of the new user if successful, -1 if the username is already taken, -2 if the email address is already taken, -3 if both are taken (or any other way to determine why it went wrong)
- atomic block
- optimal query

So far I have the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_user
  (character varying(40), character varying(255), character(60))
RETURNS integer
AS $body$
DECLARE
  id record;
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS(SELECT 0 FROM user_account WHERE username = $1 AND email_address = $2)
  THEN RETURN 3;
  ELSEIF EXISTS(SELECT 0 FROM user_account WHERE username = $1)
  THEN RETURN 1;
  ELSEIF EXISTS(SELECT 0 FROM user_account WHERE email_address = $2)
  THEN RETURN 2;
  ELSE FOR id IN INSERT INTO user_account (username, email_address, hash) values ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING user_id
       LOOP
         RETURN id;
       END LOOP;
  END IF;
  RETURN 0;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
VOLATILE
```

Would there be a more elegant way of achieving this without going through the trouble of declaring a record and having a loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the loop just store the result of the `INSERT ... RETURNING` into your variable;

```
declare 
  id integer; -- use an integer variable
begin
    ...
    ELSE 
       INSERT INTO user_account (username, email_address, hash) values ($1, $2, $3) 
       RETURNING user_id 
       INTO id; --<< here
       return id;
    END IF;
end;
```